# How to acces "this" in Nuxt's fetch() hook if "context" is passed?

Tags: nuxt.js

Usually we can access "this" in fetch() hook and use component's methods or data.

But how to access "this" if context is passed to fetch() hook?

For example, I want to call component's method inside fetch() hook which makes request to API and if nothing found throw error in maybe Nuxtish way

I tried to use `context.app.fetchKitties` instead of `this.fetchKitties`, but seems like `this` is stored in other context's property I guess

```js
fetch (context) {
  this.fetchKitties({ color: context.route.params.color })
    .catch(err => {
      if(err.status === 404) context.error({ message: "No kitty is found!", statusCode: 404})
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a context, you'll end-up with the `old fetch`.
You can use `this` directly into the `fetch()` hook, hence no need to pass the `context` as an argument (because you can access it directly).

For more info, read my comment on the github issue here: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/9564#issuecomment-882954272

Hence, use `this.$route` if you want to access it in `fetch()`.