# How to access Nuxt context inside of fetch() hook?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to access the props inside the async fetch() but I'm also using async fetch(context). So, I'm not sure how to access the props.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please be descriptive and clear about your problem, and please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AnindyaDey I'm really new to this thing. I don't know how to proceed with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Nuxt 2, you have 2 `fetch` hooks.

The old one, before Nuxt 2.12, `fetch(context)` which acts a lot like `asyncData`. It's executed before the component creation, so you don't have access to it (data, props, options... nothing).
**This one is deprecated, use `asyncData` instead.**

The new one, from Nuxt 2.12, `fetch()` (with no parameters). It's executed at the same time as the `created()` hook. It has access to the component's context (props, data, etc.).

```
fetch(context) {
  // "this" doesn't exists
  // context is the Vue global context
}

fetch() {
  this.myProp // "this" exists and have access to props
}
```

Comment: Here are more details regarding the lifecycle of Nuxt: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle#nuxt-lifecycle

Answer (score 2):

As shown in [the documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching#fetching-data), you can access the context with `this` when using the `fetch()` hook like

```js
async fetch() {
  await this.$axios // or whatever this.$i18n etc.....
}
```

Don't use `fetch(context)` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68820416/8816585).